# How to restrict access to GitHub Pages with client side SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl-certificate, github-pages

How to restrict access to GitHub Pages with client side SSL certificate?

For example, I want to have `https://username.github.io/` for public access, and `https://username.github.io/secret_place` for only connections with ssl client sertificate.

Is it possible? If yes, how to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Github pages is a static site only, and does not support any server-side code  https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/

Essentially github pages are static site hosts only, and do not include routing rules, or any verification of client certificates.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say with certainty but I'm pretty sure this isn't possible in github pages. It isn't really the github pages designed use case.